# Trying to calculate BMI with a loop?

Tags: java, methods, return

I have to do a program that loops the BMI for five people and I use scanner to input the name, weight, and height, but I can't seem to be able to return the output. I'm working with multiple methods.

The program is supposed to look like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErGCK.png)

And all I have is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i;

        System.out.println("How many BMIs do you want to compute? " + 5);

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {

            System.out.println("\n\nLoop " + i + " out of " + 5);

            System.out.print("Client's first name: ");
            String firstName = sc.next().toLowerCase();

            System.out.print("Client's weight in pounds: ");
            double weight = sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Client's height in inches: ");
            double height = sc.nextDouble();

            return;
        }



        sc.close();
    }


    public static double computeBMI(double weight, double height) {

        double bmi = ((weight * 703) / Math.pow(height, 2));

        if (bmi < 18.5 ) {
            System.out.println("underweight.\n");
        }
        else if ( (bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi < 25) ) {
            System.out.println("normal weight.\n");
        }
        else if ( (bmi >= 25) && (bmi < 30) ) {
            System.out.println("overweight.\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("obese.\n");
        }

        return bmi;

    }


    public static String printResult(String firstName, double bmi) {

        double weight;
        double height;

        System.out.printf("\nDear %s, your BMI is %.1f and you are ", firstName, bmi);
```

How can I go about it?

Comment: You are never calling `computeBMI` or `printResult` .

Comment: you are not even calling the methods

Comment: What do you mean by calling? Inside other methods?

Comment: and you're returning inside the for loop

Comment: Yes, replace `return;` with `printResult(firstName,computeBMI (weight, height));`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `main` with the following. As your current code stands, you are not even capping the methods you defined.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 int i;

 System.out.println("How many BMIs do you want to compute? " + 5);

 for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {

  System.out.println("\n\nLoop " + i + " out of " + 5);

  System.out.print("Client's first name: ");
  String firstName = sc.next().toLowerCase();

  System.out.print("Client's weight in pounds: ");
  double weight = sc.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Client's height in inches: ");
  double height = sc.nextDouble();

  printResult(firstName, (computeBMI(wight, height))); //HERE
 }
 sc.close();
 return;
}
```